# WebSockets - Files Changing

Tags: node.js, websocket

Интересует как отлавливать изменение файлов в определенном каталоге. Пока что пришло в голову сравнивать `хеши` файлов каждую секунду (?!). Скажите - это правильно? Есть ли какие-то другие идеи?

Comment: см. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify и http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=inotify

Answer (score 0):

Используйте функцию [fs.watch](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener).

P.S. Я не совсем понимаю, какое отношение к вашему вопросу имеют вебсокеты.